# Java - Use Users input in code

Tags: java, input

I am trying to build a program that talks to the user and I want it to know as much as possible. For that I need an ability to use what the user types in my programs code and not just in variables in a way that it is fully implemanted in to the code
Or if there is now way, you know of just Tell me and I will accept it.

Comment: read about `Scanner` class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner class can be used for input. Example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String age = "";
System.out.println("Please enter your age:");
age = scanner.next();
```

This code will get user input via the console.